# Setting private fields of another object instance of the same class being defined in Racket

Tags: class, object, field, racket

Let's say I have some class in Racket called `five%`:

```
(define five%
  (class object%
    (super-new)
    (define internal 5)
    (define/public (get-number)
      internal)))
```

And let's say I have defined two fives:

```
(define f (new five%))
(define g (new five%))
```

Now, both `f` and `g` have access to their own `internal` field. But lets say I want to add a function to `five%`, called, say, `change-other`, that takes in another `five%` object, and modifies it's `internal` field. Say something like this:

```
(define/public (change-other other)
  (set-field! internal other 4))
```

Now, obviously I can't do this because `internal` is a private field, and thus it cannot be accessed by any other instances of `five%`.

So, is it possible in Racket to create a class with a private field, that can only be accessed by other instances of that class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to make the field public and then use [`define-local-member-name`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/createclass.html?q=define-local-member-name#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fclass-internal..rkt%29._define-local-member-name%29%29) to turn it private.

The code would look like:

```
(define five%
  (let ()
    (define-local-member-name internal)
    (class object%
      (super-new)
      (field [internal 5])
      (define/public (change-other other)
        (set-field! internal other 4))
      (define/public (get-number)
        internal))))
```

The line `(field [internal 5])`, replaces the definition of the private field, and creates a public variant.

Then, in the same scope of the class, we use `(define-local-member-name internal)`, to turn it to a private field outside of the scope of the class.

Now, we can create two `five%` objects:

```
(define f (new five%))
(define g (new five%))
```

And in the repl, we see that `g` can mutate `f`'s field:

```
> (send g change-other f)
> (send f get-number)
4
```

But we cannot do mutate it directly:

```
> (get-field internal f)
get-field: given object does not have the requested field
  field name: internal
  object: (object:five% ...)
```

Thanks to [Asumu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/898073/asumu-takikawa) for helping with this answer.